# Docker API port binding is not working

Tags: api, docker, port

I'm trying to bind a Docker API Port on my local machine. But after restarting the docker port is not open.

Editing the Config: "**nano /etc/init/docker.conf**"

[Docker Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTQjX.jpg)

After adding this command: **DOCKER_OPTS='-H tcp://0.0.0.0:4243 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock**'

Restarting the service. But port is not open.

Please help me, where i'm going wrong ?

Thanks!

Comment: What does `ps aux|grep docker` outputs?

Comment: any news? Did you get it working?

Comment: Hey, yeah it worked. After rebooting the entire main host port was opened.  Maybe some conflict was going on.. Thanks!